# "Subscription to Publication" Verified

Tags: sql-server, replication, merge-replication

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 on a server, with SQL Server 2008 R2 Express on about 40 mobile devices. Merge replication is set up with 1 publisher & distributor server, with the mobile devices as subscribers.

I've hit a stone wall trying to investigate these errors:

> The subscription to publication 'xxxxx' could not be verified. Ensure that all Merge Agent command line parameters are specified correctly and that the subscription is correctly configured. If the Publisher no longer has information about this subscription, drop and recreate the subscription. Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL-2147201019)

While Microsoft is kind enough to include a link to help (http://help/MSSQL_REPL-2147201019), their actual message is:

> We're sorry
>   There is no additional information about this issue in the Error and Event Log Messages or Knowledge Base databases at this time. 
> You can use the links in the Support area to determine whether any additional information might be available elsewhere.

Does anyone actually know HOW SQL goes about verifying a subscription and what I can do to fix these errors?  Everything I've found up to now points to removing the subscriber, then re-subscribing, which drops the entire database and recreates it.  Not a big deal on wired clients, but the wireless subscribers can be out for as much as day due to bandwidth limitations.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Sounds like the subscriptions have expired, have you specified how long the subscriptions are valid when no syncing has been done?

Comment: These units were added with the default replication period of 14 days.  The error is showing up, in some cases, before the 14-day period expires.  What I don't know is what's going on under the hood by SQL to verify subscriptions.  Since everything is done via the SQL agent, I don't have any 'command line parameters' to specify or correct. I'd like to figure out the verification process so that I can figure out where to look next.  Thanks for the quick reply, Jimbo.